# C Beginner - Pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I'm having a little trouble understanding where my code goes wrong. I want to store into an array of strings multiple lines and after to display them; for some unknown reason after I enter a different number of lines  ( let's say 5 ), it will only display the last line 5 times. Any idea?

Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int readLine(char line[], int max);
void printLines(char *lines[], int size);

int main(){

    char *lines[100];
    char line[100];

    int i = 0;
    int len = 0;

    char *p;

    while( (len = readline(line,100)) > 0){

        if((p = malloc(len * sizeof(char))) != NULL){

            p = line;
            lines[i++] = p;
        }
    }

    lines[i] = '\0';
    printLines(lines, i);

    return 0;
}    

int readline(char line[], int max){

    if(fgets(line,max,stdin) == NULL)
        return 0;

    printf("%d \n", strlen(line));
    return strlen(line);
}

void printLines(char *lines[], int size){

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%s\n", lines[i]);
}
```

Comment: You might like to try the approach(es) described here: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ to debug your program.

Comment: Why the blank lines? Why not using braces?

Comment: You know `strlen()` doesn't include the null-char-terminator of a string, right? Maybe think about that and review your code. Between that and learning what `strcpy()` does, you may find some answers.

Comment: `p = malloc((len+1) * sizeof(char))`, `p = line;` --> `strcpy(p, line);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if((p = malloc(len * sizeof(char))) != NULL){
    p = line;
    lines[i++] = p;
```

You allocate memory for a string, and store the pointer returned from `malloc()` in `p`. Then you store a pointer to `line` in `p`, effectively throwing away the pointer to the memory you just allocated. You need to **copy** the string by using `strcpy()` or similar.

```
    strcpy (p, line);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem:

```
if((p = malloc(len * sizeof(char))) != NULL){

    p = line;
    lines[i++] = p;

}
```

`p` is a pointer that points to allocated storage first, but then its value is overwritten with the value of `line`. What you want is to copy what is currently stored at the location that `line` points to to the location where `p` points to. The function for that is `strcpy()`.

Notes:

- `sizeof (char)` is by the very definition of sizeof exactly 1.
- You will have buffer overflow issues (google that term!) if people enter lines longer than 100 chars.
- You are not really handling malloc() failure but merely skipping some code and otherwise ignoring it. Write an error message and call exit() for now if malloc() fails. Wrap that in a function for easier reuse (ofter called xalloc()).

Comment: Add to this: `malloc(len * sizeof(char))` is using `len`, which was `strlen(line)` from `readLine`, which doesn't account for space for the terminator.